# Change to username and password for database access not taking effect

Tags: c#, mysql, web-deployment, visual-studio-2017, webdeploy

I've written a small two-page site in C# MVC, it just takes some rows from a MySQL database and displays them.  It doesn't really do anything, I'm just trying to learn MVC / using C# on the web.

I had set up the MySqlConnection object up with a connection string and *finally* figured out how to deploy the site to IIS on a virtual server.  However, I had made a mistake with the username and password that I had set it up with.  The username and password worked from my machine because I was accessing from the right IP address, but there is another account (with fewer privileges) set up that can access from anywhere and the site fails, access denied.

I've gone into the code and changed the connection string to use the other MySQL account and redeployed the site.  However I'm still getting the access denied message, but with the old username and password.

How do I get it to 'forget' the old user details and use what's in the source code?

Error example (username and password redacted for obvious reasons): `[MySqlException (0x80004005): Access denied for user 'username'@'*.*.*.*' (using password: YES)]`

I have tried restarting the website in IIS and restarting IIS itself, but nothing changed.

EDIT:

Some details I should have added before, the instance of MySQL is on a different Azure virtual machine.  The username and password are in use by another web page (written in PHP) which is on an Apache web server which *is* on the same virtual machine as the database.  I've SSH'ed on the server with the database and logged into MySQL as root and confirmed the user details that I want to use exist and have the correct privileges for the database I want to access.

Comment: Are you sure it is publishing ok an you have changed every reference to the old username as it should be "remembered". Also make sure that account exists on the mysql instance on the VPS

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.

The account details are only on one line in the code and have been updated, the MySQL server I'm trying to use doesn't exist on the same Azure VM, however, it's in use by another website (hosted on the same server as the database) which does the same task, except in PHP.

I've logged in as root to MySQL on the other VM and I've checked that the user does exist and has the correct privileges.